# cyrus not deleting expunged messages

Tags: email-server, cyrus

My server (Centos 6.7 / Kolab 3.4) seems to be insisting on keeping all the emails it's ever received. The IMAP clients only show the emails that have not been deleted as expected, but looking in `/var/spool/imap/domain/e/example.com/p/user/person` (for example) shows far more emails, going back to when I started the server up (February, in this case). It's turned up as someone had mails delayed because their mailbox was 'full' today (even though they're only at 1% according to the webmail gauge). I assume the delivery agent is looking at disk use, and the webmail (IMAP) is using the emails it's expecting.

`/etc/imap.conf` has:

```
deletedprefix: DELETED
delete_mode: delayed
expunge_mode: delayed
```

`/etc/cyrus.conf` has:

```
deleteprune cmd="cyr_expire -E 4 -D 69" at=0430
expungeprune cmd="cyr_expire -E 4 -X 69" at=0445
```

but I don't know where to look to see if these are running. I can't see any errors in the logs (but am unsure where these should be - cyrus seems to post to `/var/log/maillo`g, is that right?)

I su'd to cyrus user and ran `cyr_expire` manually - reducing `-D` to `30` removed some dead mailboxes. so I figure that's probably working.

Running with `-X 69` (should remove expunged messages) I see nothing. Dropping that to 30 or even 14 still returns nothing done.

> Expunging deleted messages in mailboxes older than 14.00 days
>
> Expired 0 and expunged 0 out of 0 messages from 0 mailboxes

On several web pages it mentions 'The expiration of messages is controlled by the /vendor/cmu/cyrus-imapd/expire mailbox annotation', but I can't figure out how to list this and see if it's set correctly.

Comment: Re-read http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.4.8/man/cyr_expire.8.php and found `-a` to skip the annotation lookup this morning. Doesn't make any difference so I'm thinking it's not that now. Running out of ideas now...